# Cancel a post request with abort not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, next.js, axios

I'm trying to call a post request from Next.js app. However, there is a cancel button to stop the post request. I'm trying `abortController` with Axios (v1.4.0) to stop the post request.

When I'm calling the cancel function 'cancelUploadHandler' it's being called, but request isn't stopping.

```
  const abortController = new AbortController()

  const completeHandler = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          process.env.APP_URL + "post-url/",
          data,
          {
            onUploadProgress: (progress) => {
              console.log(progress)
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            signal: abortController.signal
          }
        );
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
          console.log("Request canceled:", error.message);
        } else {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
  };

  const cancelUploadHandler = () => {
    console.log("CANCEL REQUEST")
    abortController.abort()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t “undo” a network request that already happened. All the `abort()` does is to stop the asynchronous task related to the network in your JavaScript environment. As you can read on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal):

> The `AbortSignal` interface represents a signal object that allows you to communicate with an asynchronous operation (such as a fetch request) and abort it if required via an AbortController object.

If click the cancel button before the request has completed, you would enter the `catch` blog with an error. But for the server that's called, nothing changes.